# Set a variable to address of frame in gdb?

Tags: gdb

I need to set a local variable to the address of a particular frame obtained through backtrace. Is this possible? I haven't been able to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's a way to do it:
Select the frame you're interested in with `f *n*`,
then get the address from the instruction pointer: `set $lal=$rip`.
Enjoy.